# using c# to create a data set on IBM MVS

Tags: c#, mainframe

is there a way to create a data set via C# and pass in parameters like block length and specify fixed or variable block? I can currently ftp a file into a library that has the defined parameters but ideally, I want to be able to create a set on the fly as the file is uploaded from my machine or another server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using C# to format the strings for a FTP transmission?

If so, before you issue the PUT command try setting the file characteristics as follows...

```
QUOTE SITE LRECL=80 BLKSIZE=23440 RECFM=FB
```

For Fixed Block datasets make sure that BLKSIZE is defined as a multiple of LRECL.